# Default port not 80 when I go to a web page?

Tags: http

So I have this little add on in Chrome called Live HTTP Headers.

There is this one url I go to, lets say "www.example.com"

When I inspect the headers I see:

> GET / HTTP/1.1 Host: www.example.com:443

So port 443 is directly being asked for, but how come? Should not it be :80 ?

Comment: does the addon show you redirects? or just the final request?

Comment: The standard port number for HTTP is 80, but the standard port number for HTTPS is 443. Try visiting the page with HTTP (if possible) and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Port 443 is default port number for HTTPS, so

http://www.example.com comunicates on port 80, but

https://www.example.com comunicates on port 443.

Of course, you could always have a different port number and in this case is mandatory to explicitly show the port number in use, i.e.:

https://www.example.com:1443

Comment: @ Thanks for revision

Answer (score 0):

You can actually run a webserver on any port within the valid range of 0 to 65535.

Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) do have port recommendations for serving and receiving different types of network traffic which you can read about here  https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.txt

But technically I think you can do whatever you like.

As others pointed out 443 is the default https port. But this just means example.com have configured their webserver to serve secure http (https) content on port 443. They could if they wanted to, serve it on 8443. Most browsers however are configured to automatically send https traffic to 443 if no port is specified in the url. This means if you wanted to server https traffic on port 8443 the user would have to put in the address https://example.com:8443 explicitly.